# Local laravel web apps are not working properly after Ubuntu (and apache2) upgrade

Tags: apache, ubuntu, laravel, laravel-4, apache2

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 from 13.10, a new version of apache2 (2.4.7) was installed too. I moved all my local web apps from `var/www` to `var/www/html` which is the new default apache2 document root on Ubuntu 14.04.

My web apps are developed with Laravel and run on different vhosts like so: `example1.dev`, `example2.dev`. So I also changed the `DocumentRoot` directive in their configuration files with the correct path.

I can access the home page with no problems but any other route returns a 404 error. What do I need to change to fix this?

ps: During upgrade, the `apache2.conf` file was completely overwritten.

Comment: Try accessing your routes via example.dev/index.php/route. If it works, your `.htaccess` isn't functioning properly. Ensure Apache's mod rewrite module is enabled.

Comment: It works! But when I run `a2enmod rewrite`, it returns `Module rewrite already enabled`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating your DocRoot you generally need to update this section also in your vhost files

```
<Directory "var/www/html/example.dev/public"> 
    Options +MultiViews 
    AllowOverride All 

    <IfVersion < 2.3 > 
        Order allow,deny 
        Allow from all 
    </IfVersion> 
    <IfVersion >= 2.3> 
        Require all granted 
    </IfVersion> 
</Directory>
```

(Just an example)